# unix sort algorithm implementation

Tags: unix, sorting, algorithm

What sorting algorithm(s) is/are used in the unix `sort` command? Insertion/quicksort/etc.?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are referring to GNU sort, it implements a variant of the [**merge sort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) algorithm.

The coreutils are open source, so feel free to [**download them**](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/) and take a look.

Answer (score 6):

The [relevant POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) doesn't dictate what algorithm to use, so implementations are free to choose what they like.